# ASP.NET VB change db connection on web forms framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

I have created an instance of ASP.NET Web Forms in my Microsoft Visual Studio. By default the program generates user login page and registration which are linked to the .mdb file.

I want to reconfigure the standard connection and link it to my instance of MSSQL 2012 SQLExpress server.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I will give some direction and link you to a page.
First let me ask you this the connection you are using presently is it in a web.config file. If so this is where you will change the server/instance and database/catalog name.

[Web.Config modification for SQL Server Instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986870.aspx)

or this link

[Web Config modification for SQL Express 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sse)

So if you in the web.config file you should see something similar to this.

```
<ConnectionStrings>
<add name="" connectionString="Server=(localhost)\SqlExpress;Max Pool    Size=300;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=username;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </Connectionstrings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=  (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf;Initial    Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

you need to change the follow:
**Server** or **Data Source**
and 
**Initial Catalog** or **AttachDbFilename**

Now your credentials you may use any username and password that has access to the sql server express instance.

I hope this helps.